# How to publish Project Tango and no-Tango versions in one application?

Tags: android, augmented-reality, google-project-tango, android-augmented-reality

I want to publish an application with two apk versions:

- for devices with Project Tango support;
- for rest devices.

But when I try to publish them as is, I get *Fully shadowed APK* error on tango version (*This APK will not be served to any users because it is completely shadowed by one or more APKs with higher version codes*).

Is it possible to publish application as I want?

Comment: Given that Tango lost support on March 1, 2018: https://twitter.com/projecttango/status/941730801791549440 I don't believe you can update through store anymore.

Comment: I do know that Tango is not supported now. Yes, I can update Tango applications (I have checked this right now). And Tango is still best solution for AR prototype because Tango device Lenovo Phab 2 Pro is much cheaper than ARCore devices or new iOS devices with ARKit and is more precise in AR than them.

"Not supported" does not mean "prohibited" in Google Play.

Comment: So you know of: https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html what is different in the manifest between the two versions?

Comment: The difference is that tango version manifest has the following line:
`<uses-library
            android:name="com.projecttango.libtango_device2"
            android:required="true" />`

Comment: Given that `uses-library` isn't one of the listed ways to differentiate, all I can suggest is a runtime check and allow/block appropriately as what you want isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

Assign the higher versionCode to the Tango build.

Comment: This answer does not provide enough detail. Please provide an example or provide a more detailed explanation. Please read the SO guidelines before posting.

Comment: Thank you for this solution. This works close to what I want, but not exactly. As I have identical reqiurements (exept Tango library) in this case noAR build is shadowed by Tango. So I increased minSdkVersion for Tango build and checked that it works. However it looks like a dirt hack.